Area of the triangle formed by two adjacent squares

$ABCD$ and $AEFG$ are squares and the point $E$ lies on $AD$. If $AB=a$, find the area of the triangle $BFD$.


I noticed that if the area of the triangle is invariant by moving the point $E$ on from $A$ to $D$, the area should be $\dfrac{a^2}2$. This is because, for the special cases where $E$ is on $A$ or $D$ we can simply calculate the area. Furthermore, I could solve this problem using trigonometry. Here is my solution:
Let $GA=x$ and $\angle GBF=\alpha$, then we have $\angle FBD=\dfrac{\pi}4-\alpha$. The area of the triangle is
$$\dfrac12 BF.BD.\sin(\dfrac{\pi}4-\alpha)=\dfrac12 (a\sqrt2).\sin(\dfrac{\pi}4-\alpha).BF$$Hence, we should find the length of $BF$.
We have $$\cot\alpha=\dfrac{BG}{GF}=\dfrac{x+a}{x}=1+\dfrac ax \Rightarrow x=a\left(\dfrac1{\cot\alpha-1}\right)$$
Hence $BF$ can be calculated using Pythagorean theorem as follows:
$$BF=\sqrt{BG^2+GF^2}=a\sqrt{\left(\dfrac1{\cot\alpha-1}\right)^2+ \left(1+ \dfrac1{\cot\alpha-1}\right)^2}=a\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cot^2\alpha}{(\cot\alpha-1)^2}}=\dfrac a{\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha}$$
Finally, the area of $\triangle BDF$ is:
$$\dfrac12\times(a\sqrt2)\times \dfrac a{\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha}\times \sin(\dfrac{\pi}4-\alpha)=\dfrac{a^2}2$$

I'm looking for alternative approaches to solve this problem, preferably without using trigonometry.

Notice lines $BD$ and $AF$ are parallel, therefore, the area of $\triangle BDF$ is the same as the area of $\triangle BDA$ (same base and same height), which is clearly $a^2/2$.


Thanks! Very simple and elegant answer.

Firstly, you can prove the area is invariant when E is moved:
[Edit: this part is the same as Alma Arjuna's answer]
Draw the diagonal AF, a 45 degree line from A. Whatever the size of the left square, point F lies on that line. Therefore F moves along the line AF which is parallel to BD. If you think of BD as the base of the triangle and F its apex, the height is invariant, and hence its area too.
If you want a more algebraic method, you can do this:
Draw point $H$ to complete the rectangle $GBCH$. Let $x=|AE|=|AG|$. Then
$$A_{BFD}= A_{GBCH}-A_{GBF}-A_{BCD}-A_{DHF}\\
A_{BFD}= a(a+x) - x(a+x)/2 - a^2/2 - x(a-x)/2$$
If you simplify this, all the $x$ terms cancel, leaving just $a^2/2$.

We will prove $|\triangle DFM|=|\triangle ABM|$.
Let $|AM|=m$. Consider $x(a-m)$ and $am$. As these are double the area of the triangles, we only need prove that these are equal.
We can calculate $m$ using similar triangles, so that
$$\frac{a+x}{x}=\frac{a}{m}$$
so
$$m=\frac{ax}{a+x}$$
Then
$$x(a-m)$$
$$=x\left(a-\frac{ax}{a+x}\right)$$
$$=ax\left(\frac{a}{a+x}\right)$$
$$=a\left(\frac{ax}{a+x}\right)$$
$$=am$$
